# Optimizing Apache Spark SQL Queries

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing very long latencies on Apache Spark when running some SQL queries. In order to simplify the query, I run my calculations in a sequential manner: The output of each query is stored as a temporary table (.registerTempTable('TEMP')) so it can be used in the following SQL query and so on... But the query takes too much time, while in 'Pure Python' code, it takes just a few minutes.

```js
sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT PFMT.* , 
DICO_SITES.CodeAPI
FROM PFMT 
INNER JOIN DICO_SITES
ON PFMT.assembly_department = DICO_SITES.CodeProg """).registerTempTable("PFMT_API_CODE")

sqlContext.sql(""" 
SELECT GAMMA.*, 
(GAMMA.VOLUME*GAMMA.PRORATA)/100 AS VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER
FROM
(SELECT PFMT_API_CODE.* , 
SUPPLIERS_PROP.CODE_SITE_FOURNISSEUR,
SUPPLIERS_PROP.PRORATA 
FROM PFMT_API_CODE 
INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS_PROP ON PFMT_API_CODE.reference = SUPPLIERS_PROP.PIE_NUMERO 
AND PFMT_API_CODE.project_code = SUPPLIERS_PROP.FAM_CODE 
AND PFMT_API_CODE.CodeAPI = SUPPLIERS_PROP.SITE_UTILISATION_FINAL) GAMMA """).registerTempTable("TEMP_ONE")

sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT TEMP_ONE.* , 
ADCP_DATA.* , 
CASE 
WHEN  ADCP_DATA.WEEK  <= weekofyear(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) + 24 THEN ADCP_DATA.CAPACITY_ST + ADCP_DATA.ADD_CAPACITY_ST
WHEN  ADCP_DATA.WEEK  > weekofyear(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())) + 24 THEN ADCP_DATA.CAPACITY_LT + ADCP_DATA.ADD_CAPACITY_LT
END AS CAPACITY_REF
FROM TEMP_ONE
INNER JOIN ADCP_DATA
ON TEMP_ONE.reference = ADCP_DATA.PART_NUMBER
AND TEMP_ONE.CodeAPI = ADCP_DATA.API_CODE
AND TEMP_ONE.project_code = ADCP_DATA.PROJECT_CODE
AND TEMP_ONE.CODE_SITE_FOURNISSEUR = ADCP_DATA.SUPPLIER_SITE_CODE
AND TEMP_ONE.WEEK_NUM = ADCP_DATA.WEEK_NUM
""" ).registerTempTable('TEMP_BIS')

sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT TEMP_BIS.CSF_ID, 
TEMP_BIS.CF_ID ,
TEMP_BIS.CAPACITY_REF, 
TEMP_BIS.VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER, 
CASE 
WHEN TEMP_BIS.CAPACITY_REF >= VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER THEN 'CAPACITY_OK'
WHEN TEMP_BIS.CAPACITY_REF < VOLUME_PER_SUPPLIER THEN 'CAPACITY_NOK'
END AS CAPACITY_CHECK
FROM TEMP_BIS
""").take(100)
```

Could anyone highlight (if there are any) the best practices for writing pyspark SQL queries on Spark? 
Does it make sense that locally on my computer the script is much faster than on the Hadoop cluster? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of relaying on pure sql syntax you can use spark dataframe and spark caching abilities

Answer (score 0):

You should cache your intermediate results, what is the data source? 
can you retrieve only relevant data from it or only relevant columns. There are many options you should provide more info about your data.

Comment: There are two data sources: some come from text files, other from a hive table. I extract only the relevant columns. Moreover, I broadcast the relatively small datasets to prevent any unnecessary shuffle. Even with these optimization, I am not succeeding in running the query in an acceptable time (given the relatively small data volume).

Comment: If you use zeppelin you can cache data and each time you run a query, after the first time it will be fast. how much data is there in GB?

Comment: The data stored in the txt files are about 4 Gb. The data in hive tables are about the same.

Comment: how many cpu and ram do you have in your cluster? and how much time it takes to execute the query?

Comment: 1020 Vcores in total and 2 Tb of memory. The query takes about 2H to finish....By cashing and even with unpersisting the intermediate tables, I get the following error: container is running beyond physical memory limits....